# MYOB ODBC (Invoice generation with correct Tax calculation)

Tags: odbc, myob

We are connecting to MYOB AccountRight Enterprise v19 with ODBC direct v10.
We are creating Invoices in MYOB using the same.

1. We sent only the tax code i.e. GW in the ODBC call to MYOB, however, in that case no tax got calculated in the Invoice created in MYOB, probably the TransPost didnt work when the code was sent through ODBC
2. Then we sent the total tax (GST+WET) in the GSTAmount field as there wasn't any separate field for WET. In that case, Total tax was reflected coorectly in the Invoice generated in MYOB but the GST and WET split up was incorrect

The aim is to generate the Invoice in MYOB with correct total amount, including tax component values (GST and WET)

Please advise ASAP

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consolidated tax can be tricky to get right. Without more details I am unable to comment on precisely what you might be doing wrong; there are many possibilities, ranging from your construction of import records to the way the items and/or services you are importing are set up in the target system.

You can however test the import behaviour to find out what works best for you. The ODBC driver does not connect directly to the (ISAM) database, but invokes the import/export facility of the MYOB executable. Look at the import/export data menu option in the UI. Export sales first so you can work out the file format. You can then see what happens when you vary the data you submit.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try this at my end